# Is there a way to call a GoogleSpreadSheet add-on from a code?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to run a "Add-ons" > "Google Analytics" > "Run Reports", an option from Google Analytics Add-on (https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on), from a code. Something that looks like:

```
 Function IDontWantToClick (){
     runReports.please
     or
     acess.add-on.google-analytics.runReports(please)  

 }
```

I need to create these reports every week. My main goal is to eventually use the Trigger option on Google Api and have these reports created automatically. But for that I need to write a code that runs that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the intentional security related restrictions for add-ons disallows them from running automatically. See the [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/#run_automatically).

Comment: Is there any way to run an add-on from app-script?

Comment: No. The add-on script is kept in a separate execution "sandbox" than your document's script.